# #include __FILE__: different __FILE__'s value between compilers: what the standard says?

Tags: c, recursion, include, c-preprocessor

Sample code (`t1.c`):

```
#if defined(M1)
    printf("%s\n", __FILE__);
#undef  M1
#elif   defined(M2)
#define M1
#include __FILE__
#undef  M2
#else
#include <stdio.h>
int main    ( void )
{
    printf("%s\n", __FILE__);
#define M1
#include __FILE__
#define M2
#include __FILE__
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Results:

```
$ gcc t1.c && ./a.exe
t1.c
t1.c
t1.c

$ clang t1.c && ./a.exe
t1.c
./t1.c
./././t1.c

cl t1.c && tc1
t1.c
d:\TEMP\t1.c
d:\TEMP\t1.c
```

Compiler versions:

```
cl: 19.25.28611
gcc: 10.2.0
clang: 11.0.0
```

Question: What does the standard say?

Comment: The standard says *"The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal)*". Gives enough freedom for interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.8.1 1 says:

> The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
>
> …
>
> `__FILE__` The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).
>
> …

As the C standard specifies no other requirements for `__FILE__`, any string literal that serves as the name of the source file satisfies the requirement. It may contain or omit any sequences such as `./` as long as the string is a name for the current source file.

(There is also a note that says the presumed source file name can be changed by the `#line` directive.)

Comment: Can it be concluded that `#include __FILE__` never fails?